# react native : value of the picker does not change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

The value of the picker does not change if I select another value from it
It just happened when I added onValueChange
I would be happy to help with this

```
const [eventType, setEventType] = useState<any>();

<Picker
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => { setEventType(itemValue) }}
                dropdownIconColor='black'
                mode="dropdown">
                {stateList.map(option => <Picker.Item label={option.label} key={option.key} value={option.value} />)}
            </Picker>
```

Comment: I think you are missing `value={eventType}` on your `Picker`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this. I think you should add your code selectedValue

```js
<Picker
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => { setEventType(itemValue) }}
                selectedValue={eventType}
                dropdownIconColor='black'
                mode="dropdown">
                {stateList.map(option => <Picker.Item label={option.label} key={option.key} value={option.value} />)}
            </Picker>
```